# javascript video thumbnail preview

Tags: javascript, hover, thumbnails, preview

I found a very useful video preview:
http://www.cjboco.com/demo.cfm/project/cj-image-video-previewer/1.1.1/

I follow the instructions and i come up with a simple htm page.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="js/jquery.cj_image_video_previewer.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="Videos" class="clearfix">
<div id="preview_01" class="thumbnail">
<img src="img/1.jpg" alt="Betty Boop" width="160" height="110" />
</div>
</div>
<script>
$(".Videos #preview_01").cjImageVideoPreviewer({
        "images": [
        'img/2.jpg',
        'img/3.jpg',
        'img/4.jpg'
        ]
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm 100% sure that the path are right. But when i put the mouse hover the image nothing happens. 
Did i miss something?

Comment: do you get any errors on your browser console?

Comment: i was but was related to other code, now i shrink all the code to the simple as possible. Just to let this work, So right now i have no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bit tricky to get working, what I recommend is following the instructions and provided code from the GitHub repo found here: https://github.com/cjboco/cj-image-video-previewer

Also remember to include the right JQuery library and CJ Image Video Previewer library. In the code you provided I did not see the source for the JQuery library, that may have been part of the issue.

If you then go from the example provided in GitHub and minimize the code this is a simple example that worked:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html lang="en" class="no-js ie6"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html lang="en" class="no-js ie7"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html lang="en" class="no-js ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]><html lang="en" class="no-js ie9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

<style type="text/css">
    .Videos {
        display: block;
        height: auto;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .Videos div.thumbnail {
        border: 1px solid #999;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        height: 110px;
        margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        width: 160px;
    }
    .Videos div.thumbnailBig {
        border: 1px solid #999;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        height: 240px;
        margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        width: 320px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="Videos clearfix">
        <div id="preview_01" class="thumbnail">
            <img src="https://placehold.it/160x110" alt="test image" width="160" height="110">
        </div>
    </div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.cjboco.com/projects/cj-image-video-previewer/1.1.1/demo/jquery.cj_image_video_previewer.js"></script>
<script>
(function($) {
    'use strict';

    $('#preview_01').cjImageVideoPreviewer({
        images: [
            'https://placehold.it/160x111',
            'https://placehold.it/160x112'
        ]
    });

}(jQuery));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Many  thanks, yes i forgot to include jquery but even if i add in my page it still doesen't work. By the way if i use your code it works fine. As soon i will have spare time i'm gonna investigate why my code doesen't work and your code does. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, glad to help, yea it was definitely tricky getting this one working, happy it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the npm: `video-metadata-thumbnails`, then use it like this:

```
import { getMetadata, getThumbnails } from 'video-metadata-thumbnails';

const thumbnails = await getThumbnails(blob, {
  interval: 1,
  start: 0,
  end: 1,
  quality: 0.6
});
console.log('Preview: ', thumbnails[0]);
```